# How to add a permanent label beside entered text in an input field in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, inputbox

I have an input field in my application and I need to place a permanent label beside entered text in that input field. Also, the `styles` of the `label` to be placed are different from that of the entered text. Something like as shown below,
[image: Label of KMs placed beside entered text]

I tried replicating the behavior [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rj36bb?file=src%2FApp.js). I am able to place a label beside the entered text, but I want the label to also move forward as the characters are being typed in the input box. Currently, my entered text comes on top of the label placed, as shown below-
[image: Label overlapping with entered text]

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453215/having-a-permanent-value-in-an-input-field-while-still-being-able-to-add-text-to), but in the suggested answer, the label doesn't move with the entered text.

How can I achieve this behavior? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Styling the label differently from the input is what makes this especially challenging; they'll need to be different DOM nodes, so simpler solutions like input masking will not be sufficient.

You'll need to scale the width of the input based on its content; one way would be to use a normal `<input>` field and [resize it via javascript on every keystroke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100770/auto-scaling-inputtype-text-to-width-of-value).

Alternatively, you could use a `contentEditable` element with `display: inline-block` to automatically handle the layout; then when you're ready to do something with that value you can read its innerHTML.  A simple demonstration is below:

```js
getvalue = () => {
  console.log(document.getElementById('input').innerText)
}
```

```css
.fake_form_input {
  border: 1px solid;
  paddding: 0.2em;
}

#input {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 1em;
  padding: 0.2em;  
  outline: none;

}

.label {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="fake_form_input">
  <div contenteditable id="input">0
  </div>
  <div class="label">KM</div>
</div>

<button onclick="getvalue()">Go</button>
```

(Note that this introduces some a11y issues, you'll want to add some ARIA tagging etc if you use this technique)

Comment: Adding **outline: none** to **#input** style will hide the outline around the numbers. This way there wont be any separation with the number input and KM text.

Comment: Good suggestion, added

Answer (score 2):

Give it a try:

```js
const myInput = document.getElementById('inp');
const inputLable = document.querySelector('.inputContainer span');


myInput.addEventListener('keydown', handleLable)

function handleLable(element) {
    const charLength = element.target.value.length;
    
    inputLable.style.left = charLength * 9 + 20 < myInput.clientWidth - 40 ? charLength * 9 + 20 + "px" : myInput.clientWidth - 30 + "px";
    
}
```

```css
.inputContainer{
    position:relative;
  width:300px;
}

.inputContainer span{
    position:absolute;
    left:16px;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  color: red;
}

#inp{
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 48px;
    font-size: 16px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="inputContainer">
    <input type="text" id="inp" />
    <span>KMs</span>
</div>
```

Comment: If you type 12345 in the input, last digits are overlapping the KM

Comment: Yes, I fixed it.